# How to get current iframe reliably next time program is run?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the below code to get the current element at a cursor position, even if that element is within several iframes. I have two questions though.

1. Are all iframes located within an "iframe" tag as would be needed for the below code to work? If not, is there a more accurate way to do what I'm trying to do below?
2. How can I define the current iframe so that I can reliably return that identifier and find the same iframe next time the program is run? The element ID and session ID change each time the program is run, so if I were to manually save the iframe and use it to driver.switch_to.frame(element) next time the program ran, I know it wouldn't find it. So how can I make sure I'm in the correct iframe when locating an element after finding it this way?

Edit: To clarify, I'm attempting to create a script that works universally with any website, so the HTML of the website in this code would not be useful to include. That's why I wanted to know if all websites with iframes must use an "iframe" tag, or if there are some websites that this approach wouldn't work?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from tkinter import *
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Listener

import time

def CheckRightClick(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.right:
        if pressed:
            # Browser window position calculation script
            coordinate_script = """
                        var X, Y;
                        if (window.screenY)
                        {
                            X = window.screenX;
                            Y = window.screenY + 124;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var  Elem = document.documentElement;
                            if (!Elem.clientHeight) Elem = document.body;
                            X = Elem.scrollLeft;
                            Y = Elem.scrollTop;
                        }
                        return new Array(X, Y);
                    """
            print('Getting element')
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            winPos = driver.execute_script(coordinate_script)
            # actual element position in browser
            x -= winPos[0]
            y -= winPos[1]
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            element = driver.execute_script("""
                    return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
                """, x, y)
            # element = findElement(x, y)
            deepestElement = None
            if element is None:
                print('current cursor position might be wrong')
                return
            if element is not None:
                print(" id=> ", element.get_attribute("id"), "\n tagName=> <", element.tag_name, ">", "\n text=> ", element.text, "\n\r")
            if element.tag_name == "iframe":
                # get iframe element position. it will return {top: , left:, x: , y: , width: , height}
                elementPos = driver.execute_script("""
                    var element = document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
                    if(element !== null)
                        return element.getBoundingClientRect();
                    else
                        return null;
                """, x, y)
                # actual element postion in the iframe.
                x -= elementPos['left']
                y -= elementPos['top']
                driver.switch_to.frame(element)
                deepestElement = driver.execute_script("""
                    return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
                """, x, y)
            else:
                deepestElement = element
            if deepestElement is not None:
                print("deepest element:\n id=> ", deepestElement.get_attribute("id"), "\n tagName=> <", deepestElement.tag_name, ">", "\n text=> ", deepestElement.text, "\n\r")
            print('Element at cursor is ', deepestElement, "\n\r")
            #deepestElement.click()
            # click_window.event_generate("<<quit>>")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'./chromedriver_90.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C:\Users\David\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32'r'\chromedriver.exe')

url = 'http://store.cardsagainsthumanity.com/'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

click_window = Tk()
click_prompt = Label(click_window, text='Right click somewhere')
click_prompt.grid(row=3, column=3)
click_window.bind("<<quit>>", lambda *args: click_window.destroy())
listener = Listener(on_click=CheckRightClick)
listener.start()
click_prompt.mainloop()
listener.stop()
```

Comment: Can you show some samples of what the different types of HTML look like for your iframe element?

Comment: I'm trying to create a script that works universally, so it wouldn't be helpful to show a specific website. I'm actually trying to use a range of websites to test this script to make sure it works with any element regardless of how many iframes there are. Which is why I wanted to know if the structure of this code targeting an "iframe" tag would work universally.

Comment: Before your `driver.switch_to.frame(element)` I think you should add a check to make sure that element is actually the iframe you need to target. Right now I think `element` is just passing in the first iframe that's found on the page.

Comment: Regarding this "That's why I wanted to know if all websites with iframes must use an "iframe" tag,"... Yes, any `iframe` element will have an `iframe` tag. You would run into issues with nested iframes because searching for selector `iframe` will not return nested iframes (you have to switch to the outer iframe, then locate the child iframe... and so on, if you happen to have several nested iframes).  Also, there are `frame` elements you sometimes need to switch to as well.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I figured that wouldn't be able to target nested iframes, and I also don't know if I need to driver.switch_to.iframe instead of driver.switch_to_frame. I've actually been trying to do this one thing for about 3 months now, and have read everything I can find online and paid several people to help. But people usually predefine this stuff for specific webpages, so I can't figure out how to get the information I need at runtime. 

Do I need to do iframe instead of frame when switching?

Comment: And should I turn the if statement that looks for the iframe tag into a while statement, and maybe have a variable that keeps track of the order to switch the frames? But how can I know if I'm targeting the correct frame? This code is supposed to grab the deepest child element at the cursor position, so I can't make sure the frame has the element I'm looking for until I figure out what that element is.

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame()` is the correct syntax. If you want to contact me offsite, and then we can share more details, we can likely work out a solution for exactly what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233068/discussion-between-c-peck-and-thenomadicaspie).

Comment: there is also "<frame>"... used with framesets "<frameset>"... this is the old-school way to do it and I believe is still supported.  (the same webdriver method would work there... switchToFrame()) There are also sandbox settings for <iframe>s, so nothing is going to work universally.  (They can turn off javascript, form subsmission, etc...:  https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_iframe_sandbox.asp )